# slide down accordion list that remembers its state if open or close

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;">
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link1">main link 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
<div class="wpsc_categorisation_group">
    <ul class="wpsc_categories wpsc_top_level_categories">
        <li><a href="link2">main link 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>test 1</a></li>
                <li><a>test 2</a></li>
                <li><a>test 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear_category_group"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li {position:relative;}
div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li ul {display:none;}

ul.wpsc_top_level_categories {padding-bottom:0 !important;}
ul.wpsc_top_level_categories li {}
ul.wpsc_top_level_categories li:hover {cursor:pointer;}
ul.wpsc_top_level_categories li ul li a span {background:none !important;}
span.collapse-arrow {background:red;width:10px;height:9px;float:right;margin-top:5px;}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li ul').slideUp().hide();
jQuery('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li').click(function() {
jQuery(this).parent().find('ul').slideToggle();
    });
jQuery('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li a').append('<span class="collapse-arrow">&nbsp;</span>');
```

this is My jsfidlle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vs9nc/)

I really need help on this one...

1. I need the red box only to be clickable and subs will slidedown
2. and also need it to remember if user opens it or closes it, so when changing page it will remember its state
3. and also HTML should not be altered because i'm editing in wpsc widget

I really appreciate any help I can get... :-(

Comment: Fiddle that can be worked with http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nwbY7/

Comment: Hi, what did it changed? @Sushanth--

Comment: Nothing..  just created a fiddle if anyone wants to work with :)

Comment: need help...

1. only the red square is able to slide down its sub-categories not the link
2. links will be links and when clicked it redirects
3. how could it remember its last open/close state when changing pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .. For the First Requirement..

```
$('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li ul').slideUp().hide();
$('.wpsc_categories').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // Prevent the Default Action
    if (e.target.className == 'collapse-arrow') { // Trigger only
                                                  // If clicked on span
        $(this).closest('ul').find('ul').slideToggle();
    }

});
$('div.wpsc_categorisation_group ul li a')
   .append('<span class="collapse-arrow">&nbsp;</span>');​
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/nwbY7/2/)

**Delegating** the click event to the Anchor and toggling the ul only if clicked on the span with class `collapse-arrow` ..

**2nd** req is a bit different were in, if you are going to a different page you can store the state either in a cookie or session and  repopulate on every page load.
**3rd** -- No HTML was changed in the context

Comment: Thanks for that :-)

I hope someone answers My second question

Comment: is the second requirement hard to do in My case? what should I use to achieve this. sorry I am new in this :-(

Comment: Just store the value in this cookie .. When page loads then retrieve its state and set it .. Yay!!

Comment: thanks, but I really dont know how to use jquery.cookie.js

maybe I should ask some help for this, why am I so inexperience... :-(

Comment: Hello, I had a bit of a problem here in the second requirement, it seems that the links are not accessible

Comment: You need to download the js file into your project an duse them

Comment: Open this file jquery.cookie.js and use it in your project